# Some definitions don't one box nicely

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

```
define: everyone  
define: helping
```

In chat, this looks like:

[image: everyone is not helping]

Yea, broken icons - but that's not the issue.  Its how its rendered.  Helping is nicely rendered. Everyone is not.  The [Wikitionary for `everyone`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/everyone) is a bit... messed up, compared to the much more standardized [`helping`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/helping).

If I were to take a guess, it would be that 'Etymology' section.  The wiki markdown:

```
==English==

===Etymology===
From {{etyl|enm|en}} {{m|enm|everichon}}, equivalent to {{compound|every|one|lang=en}}.

===Pronunciation===
* {{a|US}} {{IPA|/ˈɛv.ɹi.wʌn/|lang=en}}
* {{audio|en-us-everyone.ogg|Audio (US)|lang=en}}

===Pronoun===
{{en-pron}}
```

vs

```
==English==

===Pronunciation===
* {{audio|en-us-helping.ogg|Audio (US)|lang=en}}

===Noun===
{{en-noun}}
```

It really shouldn't cause that much of a problem like is shown.  Things are at the same heading level - just a different section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the problem was that we didn't list "pronoun" as one of the sections we were pulling out to read, and no other sections matched - so when it came to render it had nothing to say. The fallback strategy was to dump some of the raw data. Fixing.

Here it is now (taken from my local machine):

[image]